# Could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am testing the "fabcar" repository in hyperledger fabric samples. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples

While i am trying to load the path of java smart-contract in startFabric.sh file https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/startFabric.sh by putting CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=${1:-"java"} its giving me the following error.

Error: Could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0

One can checkout the repo for corresponding codes.
Smart-Contracts of "go" and "javascript" are working completely fine but in java it is showing errors while instantiating the chaincode on channel.
I am trying hard but not getting through it and can someone please suggest me how to write smart contracts in java.(like gradle file for java smart contract)

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependency in the `build.gradle`.

```
compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java', name: 'fabric-chaincode-shim', version: '1.x'
```

Change the  '1.x' to '1.4.2'.